# Tilemap missing collision options?

Tags: collision-detection, tilemap, godot-4

I've been having a lot of trouble getting tiles to have collision in the newest Godot 4 beta10.

I thought there was supposed to be a physics tab that would give collision options like in previous betas, but maybe that was removed?

[image: This is what I see:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you edit tile collision shapes has changed in Godot 4.

1. First click the `TileSet` assets in the tilemap inspector, and additional editing options appear.

[image]

[image]

2. Add elements in the `Physics Layers` tab.

[image]
[image]

3. The physical layer you just added will appear in the `Paint` tab, click it.

[image]

4. Then you can edit the collision information of this physical layer, hope this helps.

[image]